# if else statement simplification for better readibility

Tags: c#

I have written a small snippet that gets the job done, but I wonder if there is any way to make it more readable, or compact?

```
if (x && !y) var = 2;
else if (!x && y) var = 4;
else if (x && y) var = 24;
else if (!x && !y) var = 0;
SetStatus(true, var);
```

Comment: The values are bit strange (`24, 2, 4, 0`). Do you have `if (x && !y) var == 2;`, not `if (x && !y) var == 20;`? Isn't `2` a typo? Please, note `2` and `20`. If you have `20` then `var = 20 * (x ? 1 : 0) + 4 * (y ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing you could do is re-order those cases into something a bit more logical:

```
if (x && y) result = 24;
else if (x && !y) result = 2;
else if (!x && y) result = 4;
else result = 0;
```

You could break it up a bit, grouping on the x's:

```
if (x)
{
    if (y)
        result = 24;
    else
        result = 2;
}
else
{
    if (y)
        result = 4;
    else
        result = 0;
}
```

Then you can collapse those inner if's into ternaries:

```
if (x)
{
    result = y ? 24 : 2;
}
else
{
    result = y ? 4 : 0;
}
```

Heck, you could do the whole thing as ternaries if you wanted:

```
result = x
    ? (y ? 24 : 2)
    : (y ? 4 : 0);
```

You could also use a switch expression:

```
result = (x, y) switch
{
    (true, true) => 24,
    (true, false) => 2,
    (false, true) => 4,
    (false, false) => 0,
}
```

"Readable" is somewhat subjective: choose something which is readable to you and your team.

Comment: @Adrian Disagreed. The question is asking for ways which are more compact (objective) or elegant (subjective). It can be answered by highlighting areas of C# syntax which OP might not be aware of, and letting them decide which is more elegant to them. Notice how my answer doesn't give any opinions

Comment: @Adrian Be nice, please: we're here to be helpful and constructive, and calling each other "ridiculous" doesn't help anything :) I said "more compact (objective) or elegant (subjective)", and my answer says ""Elegant" is subjective: choose something which is readable to you and your team" (I noticed it was partially wrong just prior to my previous comment, and fixed it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224970/discussion-between-canton7-and-adrian).

Comment: @Adrian No, regardless of whether it's on-topic for SO, it's definitely off-topic on code-review.

Comment: I've edited the "elegant" bit out of the question. You can go ahead and edit the answer if you want as well.

Comment: @Adrian  More importantly, it's not a complete working code, it's just a snippet. Short can be ok for code-review, though I would generally expect something more substantive.

Comment: @Adrian Move this to the chat linked above, please